# swift 3 post request token mismatch exception

Tags: swift, laravel-5, http-post, token

I'm sending post request to an API route written in php/laravel,

(check [csrf-protecion](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#csrf-protection) from laravel doc)

**swift**

```
let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://my.api/post")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("Ag1D3YC6DbxuwYNgwUhmNoVkfFnchlrPXQB4rR11", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-CSRF-TOKEN")
        let postString = "id=13&name=Jack"

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }
            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")
        }.resume()
```

**php/laravel**

```
// route.php
Route::post('post', 'PostController@post');
Route::get('token', function() {
   return csrf_token(); // this is how I get token for request header
}); 
// PostController.php
public function post(Request $request)
{
   return $request->all();
}
```

I keep receiving `TokenMismatchException` error within Swift code while I can post successfully via Postman app,

any idea?

Comment: Did you double check if the token right?

Comment: With third party API, you may face this issue. you can skip CSRF tocken check via middleware check for this particular request

Comment: @Rupal thanks that works! but is there another way not to skip it?

Comment: No, I don't think so. as we don't have control on any third party site. we are sending data from our application. they take and proceed it and return back something to us. but they won't provide us our original token OR may be if they provide even then once it back to our application, it got changed. so it will never match.